# Having trouble binding to a dependencyProperty

Tags: c#, silverlight, binding, dependency-properties

**MyControl.xaml.cs**

```
public string achName
{
    get { return (string)this.GetValue(achNameProperty); }
    set { this.SetValue(achNameProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty achNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("achName", typeof(string), typeof(MyControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
 <My:MyControl achName="{Binding Name}"/>
```

name has a value, but it doesn't seem to get send to the dependendcy (achName) property. How can I fix this?

**ViewModel**

```
public string Name { get { return "some random test value"; } }
```

other bindings to viewmodel do work, so the problem doesn't lie there.

Comment: Check your output window. May be name property is not getting binded properly to your view.

Comment: You can test this by putting textBox and binding its text to `name` property. See if text appears.

Comment: name property is binded, i've tested this with a textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason i can see is that `Binding` to `Name` is failing. You can debug your bindings to see if its not failing. Refer to this - [Debug Data Bindings](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx)

Comment: Doh,  I was doing this.. but at the wrong moments. Seems it's searching for name in MyControl instead of my Viewmodel!  Think I can manage from here again. thank you very much!

Comment: Oh,that happens sometimes with me too.. :)